# headers в data-table и несколько JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

```
  headers () {
  return [
    { text: 'Status', value: 'status' },
    { text: 'Typ', value: this.tdTyp[+'typ' + -1].bezeichnung },
  ]}
```

В data хранится JSON tdTyp, который я хочу использовать вместе с JSON который и формирует таблицу. Сейчас таблица работает, но если добавляю ряд "Typ", то получаю ошибку:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bezeichnung')
```

Без data-table, аналогичную таблицу формировал с помощью v-for и все работало:

```
<td>{{ td.status }}</td>
<td>{{ $data.tdTyp[td.typ - 1].bezeichnung }}</td>
```

Как в [data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) сделать правильно?
Возможно, тут нужна постообработка этой таблицы: брать число из этого столбца и смотреть по нему индекс в JSON tdTyp ? но как это сделать?

Comment: Выражение " +'typ' + -1 " равно NaN. Можете сами в консоли проверить. Это так к слову, на самом деле информации недостаточно, чтоб точно определить, что не так

Comment: @Anynomius это да. { text: 'Typ', value: 'typ' } но в таком виде 'typ' - это число. Я просто хотел сделать там конкатенацию с помощью плюсов(синтаксис не знаю какой там подойдет), а должно было получится{ text: 'Typ', value: this.tdTyp[1].bezeichnung }. В таком виде ошибки нет, но и ничего не выводится

Comment: `${this.tdTyp['typ' - 1].bezeichnung}` так то же не работает в обратных кавычках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для v-data-table лучше всего использовать [item.* slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots).

Чтобы все работало нужно создать #item.status(опционально: там будут отображаться картинки) и #item.typ слоты.

Поля headers нужно сделать просто как данные вместо computed добавить getTyp method, чтобы там вычеслить 'Typ'

Примерный код:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="tdData"
>
  <template #item.status="props">
    <td>
      <img v-if="props.item.status === 1"
           src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/docs/images/logos/vuetify-logo-dark.svg"
           height="30"
      />
    </td>
  </template>
  <template #item.typ="props">
    <td>
      {{ getTyp(props.item.typ) }}
    </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>

...

data() {
  return {
    headers: [
      { text: 'Status', value: 'status' },
      { text: 'Typ', value: 'typ'}
    ],
    tdData: resTdData,
    tdTyp: resTdTyp
  }
},
methods: {
  getTyp(typId) {
    if (this.tdTyp[typId - 1] !== undefined) {
      return this.tdTyp[typId - 1].bezeichnung;
    } else {
      return '-';
    }
  }
}
```

[Пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/rNGZPBL)